# How to add email signatures to the end of email message

Tags: gmail

Gmail has settings to add signatures at the end of the email thread (i.e. right at the bottom of the email thread). Would it be possible to add the signature immediately after we type the subject / message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can quite easily with signature tweaks in Gmail.

1. Click the cog button on the right
2. From the drop-down menu, click **Settings**
3. Click **Labs**
4. Search for "Signature tweaks"
5. Enable Signature Tweaks
6. Save Changes

Now when you reply to an email, the signature will be directly after the subject line.

[Here](http://www.clickonf5.org/3619/append-gmail-signature-top/) is a description with some images.

Comment: The _Signature Tweaks_ lab "graduated" some time ago, so this solution no longer works. This is now part of the general settings. Please see [this answer](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/54591/354).

Answer (score 1):

This can be found in the General section of your Gmail settings. Scroll down to "Signature:".

To have your signature appear *above* any quoted text, simply make sure the box labeled

> Insert this signature before quoted text in replies and remove the "--" line that precedes it

is checked. If unchecked, Gmail will append your signature at the end of all text (and put the standard "--" before it so mail clients will recognize the start of the signature block).

[image: signature setting]

Answer (score -3):

**You can easily use this while accessing this scenario.**

[image]

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question of how to put the signature at the top of the text.